# Combining Spark schema without duplicates?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, apache-spark-1.6

To process the data I have, I am extracting the schema before, so that when I read the dataset, I provide the schema instead of going through the expensive step of inferring schema.

In order to construct the schema, I need to merge in several different schema into the final schema, so I have been using `union (++)` and `distinct` methods, but I keep getting `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Duplicate column(s)` exception.

For example, say we have two schema in the following structure:

```
val schema1 = StructType(StructField("A", StructType(
    StructField("i", StringType, true) :: Nil
    ), true) :: Nil)

val schema2 = StructType(StructField("A", StructType(
    StructField("i", StringType, true) :: Nil
    ), true) :: Nil)

val schema3 = StructType(StructField("A", StructType(
    StructField("i", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("ii", StringType, true) :: Nil
    ), true) :: Nil)

val final_schema = (schema1 ++ schema2 ++ schema3).distinct

println(final_schema)
```

which outputs:

```
StructType(
    StructField(A,StructType(
         StructField(i,StringType,true)),true), 
    StructField(A,StructType(
        StructField(i,StringType,true),    
        StructField(ii,StringType,true)),true))
```

I understand that only schema structure that exactly match another schema will get filtered out by `distinct`. However I want the result to look like this:

```
StructType(
    StructField(A,StructType(
        StructField(i,StringType,true),    
        StructField(ii,StringType,true)),true))
```

in which all the gets "combined" into one schema. I have sifted through all the methods in [scala documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) but I cannot seem to find the right method to solve this. Any ideas?

EDIT:

The end goal will be to feed in `final_schema` to `sqlContext.read.schema` and read RDD of JSON strings using `read` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(schema1 ++ schema2 ++ schema3).groupBy(getKey).map(_._2.head)
```

where `getKey` is a function that goes from a schema to the properties you want to consider for merging (for example the column name or the name of the sub fields). In the `map` function you can take the head or use some more elaborate function to keep a specific schema.

Comment: Any chance you know what a similar solution using PySpark would look like?

Answer (score 1):

**Spark with Scala:**

```
val consolidatedSchema = test1Df.schema.++:(test2Df.schema).toSet
val uniqueConsolidatedSchemas = StructType(consolidatedSchema.toSeq)
```

**Spark with Java:**

```
StructType consolidatedSchema = test1Df.schema().merge(test2Df.schema());
```